# How to run variable in Netezza?

Tags: netezza

I am trying to run some code in Aginity for Netezza without putting it in a stored procedure, but I can't get the syntax right. Here is some sample code below.

```
\set STARTDATE '2016-01-19 00:00:00';
\set ENDDATE '2016-01-19 23:59:59';
select * from LOG where create_time between :STARTDATE and :ENDDATE;
```

and the error is this:

> error ^ found ":" (at char 60) expecting an identifier found a keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
set $startdate = '2016-01-19 00:00:00';
set $enddate = '2016-01-19 23:59:59';
select * from LOG where create_time between $startdate and $enddate;
```

Comment: It went well.Thank you for your help.